# Question regarding a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the question:

> Let $H$ be any subgroup of $S_n$. Then $H$ either contains only even
>   permutations, or $H$ contains the same number of odd or even
>   permutations.

Suppose $P$ be the proposition that **H contains even permutations** and $Q$ be the proposition that **H contains the same number of odd as even permutations**. Then we have to show that $P \land \lnot Q$ or $\lnot P \land Q$.

Here is the proof for $P \land \lnot Q$ i.e. $H$ contains only even permutations. Let $h_1, h_2 \in H$. Then $h_1, h_2$ are even. It can also be easily shown that $h_1h_2$ is even. Thus, $h_1h_2 \in H$ and hence $H$ is closed. Also let $h\in H$. It can also be easily shown that $h^{-1} \in H$, thus, showing $H$ is closed with respect to inverses. And by the two test subgroup test, we have verified that $H$ is indeed a subgroup.

However, I'm finding it difficult to show $\lnot P \land Q$ i.e. $H$ contains the same number of odd as even permutations. I'm thinking of starting off like this: Let $O$ be the set of $n$ distinct odd permutation, say $O=\{ o_1, o_2, \dots , o_n\}$. Pick some $o_i$ from $O$ and define the set $E:=\{ o_1o_i, o_2o_i, \dots , o_no_i\}$. Clearly, $E$ is the set of $n$ distinct even permutations. Now, let $H=E\cup O$. Clearly, $H$ contains same number of even and odd permutations. We'll be done if we show $H$ is a subgroup. Now, I find it difficult to claim inverses exist and $H$ is closed. Is there any other way to show it?

Comment: Your logic is wrong. To prove that $H$ contains either only even permutations or that it has the same number of even and odd permutations, you have to prove the following statement: If $H$ contains both an even and odd permutation, then it contains the same number of even and odd permutations.

Comment: @uniquesolution _Technically_, the statement we need to prove begins "If $H$ contains any odd permutations", not "if $H$ contains both even and odd permutations". I am aware that since $e\in H$ is even, the two are equivalent. I was just thinking, since we are trying to be logical here, we should negate our sentences correctly.

Comment: You are somewhat correct, Arthur. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a group homomorphism $\mathsf{sign}:S_n\to\{1,-1\}$ sending all even permutations to $1$ and all odd permutations to $-1$. Here $\{1,-1\}$ is equipped with common muliplication.

If $i:H\to S_n$ denotes the inclusion then composition: $$\phi:=\mathsf{sign}\circ i:H\to\{1,-1\}$$ is a group homomorphism.

Discern two cases: $\phi$ is surjective or $\phi$ is not surjective.

If it is not surjective then every element of $H$ must be sent to $1$ hence is even.

If it is surjective and $K$ denotes its kernel (i.e. the set of even permutations in $H$) then $H/K$ and $\{1,-1\}$ are isomorphic so that $[H:K]=2$.

Comment: I am yet to learn homomorphism apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you haven't shown $H$ contains only even permutations. It seems like you implicitly defined $H$ as the set of **all** even permutations, and you showed that this set is closed under composition and inverses, making it a subgroup. This shows the existence of at least one subgroup $H$ containing only even permutations, but that's not helpful for answering the given question: even if every subgroup $H$ contained the same number of odd and even permutations, and none contained only even permutations, it would still be true that "either $H$ contains only even permutations or $H$ contains the same number of odd and even permutations."

What you need to do is show that an arbitrary subgroup $H$ -- not one already defined -- fulfills the given criteria. Perhaps you can assume that it doesn't fulfill the criteria (i.e., that it contains at least one odd permutation and an unequal number of odd and even permutations), so that you have some structure in $H$, and then derive a contradiction.